# data table correct syntax of this ajax for data table/ other way

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am having trouble with this in my code i am in the situation in which my code doesn't work good. Here it is.

I am using a codeigniter from this, i am having a trouble from the situation with this code below where i want to alert the total and execute my data table data. I am populating my data table data from my controller,

In the code below, i manage to alert the total but my data table is not working, it returns no data available

```
function data_table_report(dateselected){
        $("#dataTables-report").dataTable().fnDestroy();

        table =  $('#dataTables-report').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('patients_report/dataTable_report/')?>"+dateselected,
                "type": "POST",
                "dataSrc": function (data) {
                  alert(data.total);
                  return data;
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            bInfo: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{ extend: 'colvis', columns: ':not(:first-child)'}]
        });
    }
```

but when i change my code with these below, my data table responds with data but it will not alert the total.

```
function data_table_report(dateselected){
        $("#dataTables-report").dataTable().fnDestroy();

        table =  $('#dataTables-report').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('patients_report/dataTable_report/')?>"+dateselected,
                "type": "POST",

            },
            responsive: true,
            bInfo: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{ extend: 'colvis', columns: ':not(:first-child)'}],
            "dataSrc": function (data) {
                  alert(data.total);
            }
        });
    }
```

what should i do to alert my total from ajax and also my data table will function well.

Comment: have you tried to alert only data? What it is returning?

Comment: Is the "dataSrc" object not in the wrong spot, doesn't it have to be in the ajax object ?

Comment: what about `alert(data.length);`? check it

Comment: @JayminsFakeAccount yes i manage to alert te data.total in my first code, but my data table doesn't work..

Comment: @BrentBoden thats what my question is, what would be the goodspot for my datatable will work and also my alert

Comment: @JcJohn  did you checked what i tell?

Comment: @Anant cant create fiddle,. i dont know how to use with codeigniter with that and also including jquery files

Comment: any answers please.

Comment: @JcJohn  can you tell me what is the output of this:-`"<?php echo site_url('patients_report/dataTable_report/')?>"+dateselected,` (means url) so that i can try to create an example itself.